# generating histogram for a single column table in SAS

Tags: sas, histogram

I have a table with a single column and I wish to generate a histogram based on the column of the table.

```
age
---
22 
33
40
74

ods graphics / reset width=6.4in height=4.8in imagemap;

proc sgplot data=WORK.COMBINE;
    title height=14pt "Displaying maximum";
    histogram age / showbins;
    density age;
    density age / type=Kernel;

run;

ods graphics / reset; title;
```

The problem I am facing is that it is not displaying the numbers against corresponding y axis. Although I have just a single column but I want to show the histogram with highest figure grow up while each of the values maintain its correspondence on the Y axis but to my surprise even the highest value is shorter than lowest value

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.   I think you may misunderstand the y-axis of a histogram, or you may want a different type of plot.  If you run your code and make a histogram of height or weight in sashelp.class (or one of the other sashelp datasets), does it look like you expect?

Comment: Yes it does but in my case, it is not working

Comment: Can you post an example of your data, maybe 10-20 records where the histogram you get does not match what you expect?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the output created? Are you looking for a cumulative frequency plot ?

Comment: @Richard yes, I only used age as an example. I did a distinct count of 4 tables and created a single table with a single field name called count and respectful values as 44, 47, 68 and 73

Comment: @Quentin the picture is what was displayed in the answer below but I want it in other examples but there is no range as indicated by Richard using age < 18 and > 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just those 4 data values the histogram looks like this:

[image]

The plotting routine computes the age range for the bins and where the bin centers are.  The computation is some internal algorithm that you have some control over with `histogram` statement options `/ binstart= binwidth= nbins=`.

Of course the histogram bars are for the bins and the height is scaled to the relative count of values falling into the bin.  The y-axis will be either actual count or percentage of counts.  You had 4 values falling into 3 bins, so one of the bins will have a count of 2 (or 50% = 2/4).  The highest value bar is shorter then the lowest value bar because there were fewer high values than low values.

What happens when you have more data ?

Here is some code that creates 250 values conforming to a normal distribution and histograms them, a cumulative frequency needle plot is also shown.

```
data work.have;
  do personid = 1 to 250;
    do until (18 <= age <= 60);
      age = floor(18 + (32 + sqrt(62) * rannor(123)));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc freq noprint data=have;
  table age / out=freq outcum;  * data for needle plot;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
    title height=14pt "Default bins";
    histogram age / showbins;
    density age;
    density age / type=Kernel;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
    title height=14pt "binstart=20 binwidth=2";
    histogram age / showbins binstart=20 binwidth=2;
    density age;
    density age / type=Kernel;
run;

proc sgplot data=freq;
    title height=10pt "cum_freq needle plot of data from Proc FREQ output";
    needle x=age y=cum_freq;
run;
```

[image]

More sample code showing effects of `nbins` and `xaxis`

```
ods graphics / reset width=500px height=250px imagemap;
proc sgplot data=have;
    title  height=12pt "binstart=0 nbins=25";
    title2 height=12pt "xaxis min=0 max=100";
    histogram age / showbins binstart=0 binwidth=2 nbins=50;
    density age;
    density age / type=Kernel;
    xaxis min=0 max=100;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
    title  height=12pt "binstart=0 nbins=10";
    title2 height=12pt "xaxis min=-100 max=200";
    histogram age / showbins binstart=0 binwidth=2 nbins=50;
    density age;
    density age / type=Kernel;
    xaxis min=-100 max=200;
run;
```

[image]

For the case of viewing distributions of a variable in different categorical groups you might want to step up to SGPANEL:

```
data work.have2;
  do year = 2017, 2018;
  do group = 'Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C';
  do _n_ = 1 to 250;
    personId + 1; 
    do until (18 <= age <= 95);
      age = floor(6 + (32 + sqrt(95) * rannor(123)));
    end;
    output;
  end;
  end;
  end;
run;

ods graphics / reset;

title;
proc sgpanel data=have2;
  panelby year group / layout=lattice;
  histogram age;
  xaxis 
run;
```

[image]

Comment: What a lovely one but in case I want to use it for other data lets count-> 44, 47, 68, 73. Because the condition you gave was for age but in a situation where there is no range like a count, can someone range it from 1-100?

Comment: You can control the range of the age axis using just number of bins `histogram age / showbins binstart=0 nbins=50;`  SGPLOT will compute the axis tic mark numbers such that they fit reasonably.  The SGPLOT statement `XAXIS min= max=` also control the horizontal axis the histogram is drawn on.

Comment: Ok thanks but please can you help to reflect in the answer you provided above. Thanks